# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element in Twilio

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I am running the following code, and it is showing me this error. Can someone tell me why is my xml giving a problem? When i run this in the browser I get:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
```

When I run this through Twiilio I get the following error

```
parserMessage    Error on line 2 of document : Content is not allowed in prolog.

<?php

    header("content-type: text/xml");
      echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    require "twilio-php-latest/Services/Twilio.php";

        /* Set our AccountSid and AuthToken */
    $AccountSid = "xxxxx";
    $AuthToken = "xxxx";

    include 'db.php';
    $caller=$_REQUEST['From'];
    /* Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client */
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    $from= "+17864310795";
    $student_number=substr($caller,1);
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $studentData=getSingleStudentData($db,$student_number);
    foreach($studentData as $key=>$val)
    {
        $student_id=$val['student_id'];
        $phone=$val['phone_number'];
        $status=$val['status'];
        echo $student_id;
        // find out last call successfully completed by the student
        if($status==1)
        {
            $progress = getLastActivity($db,$student_id);
X
X
X
echo "done with initialize<br/>";
            $server= "http://sample.com";


        try {
            $to = '+' . $phone;            
            echo $phone;
            $questions_id_url='questions_id_0='.$questions_id[0].'&questions_id_1='.$questions_id[1].'&questions_id_2='.$questions_id[2];
            $questions_file_url='questions_file_0='.$questions_file[0].'&questions_file_1='.$questions_file[1].'&questions_file_2='.$questions_file[2];
            $url = $server.'/startCall.php?call_id='.$call_id.'&phone='.$phone.'&'.$questions_id_url.'&'.$questions_file_url.'&student_id='.$student_id.'&story='
            .$story.'&story_id='.$story_id.'&call_number='.$call_number.'&question_number=0&count_english=0&count_hindi=0&insert_receivecall=0';
            echo "here"."-----".$url;
            $client->account->calls->create(
            "+17864310795",
            $to,
            $url,
            array(
            'Method' => "GET",
            'FallbackMethod' => "GET",
            'StatusCallbackMethod' => "GET",
            'Record' => "false",
            ));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // log error
        }
        }
    }
?>
<Response>
     <Reject reason="busy"/>
</Response>
```

I have tried everything, and was hoping I could spot the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think your problem is that you're pushing out more than just XML within that script. You start by setting the content type to XML and `echo`ing the XML declaration, but after that you start to `echo` what looks like debugging commands, which aren't valid XML, so the parser throws an error.

So, to start, I would comment out or remove anything that `echo`s non XML content from your script.

Let me know if that helps.