# table data downloaded to XML format in php - error: junk after document element

Tags: php, xml, download

I have table data with headings:
**Keyword,Search Times, Last Search,Delete** 
and I am providing a link to download the table data in XML format .

My code is:

```
    public function download_xml()
  {
//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "user";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "password";
$config['db_name']    = "db_name";
$config['table_name'] = "tablename";

 //connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");
$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s"; //fruits
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";

//select all items in table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$config['table_name'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {  
      //$key holds the table column name
         $xml .= "<".$key.">";
             //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
         $xml .= "<![CDATA[".$value."]]>";

         //and close the element
         $xml .= "</".$key.">";
      }

      $xml.="</".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}
//close the root element
$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send the xml header to the browser
//header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
 header ("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=latin1"); 
//output the XML data
echo $xml;

  }
```

Linking is done by providing a link at view:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Export to XML ',array('controller'=>'admin','action'=>'download_xml'), array('target'=>'_self'));
?>
```

It's giving me error:

```
    XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
    Location: http://www.abc.co.uk/admin/download_xml
    Line Number 1, Column 173285:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><search_logss><search_logs><id><![CDATA[27]]></id><keyword><![CDATA[LRG Core Collection]]></keyword><user_id><![CDATA[0]]></user_id><priority><![CDATA[30]]></priority><created><![CDATA[2014-11-28 06:57:59]]></created><modified><![CDATA[2015-04-05 09:13:21]]></modified></search_logs></search_logss><!DOCTYPE html>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Is anyone having idea why is it so?
Thanx in advance

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762857/xml-parsing-error-junk-after-document-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008046/xml-parsing-error-junk-after-document-element-in-twilio.. are you echoing something? or blank spaces are coming in betweent he xml tags...

Comment: this is my entire code and I have no clue as I m not able to spot the error

Comment: check is there blank spaces coming in your code or what...

Comment: No space is coming as it's showing :
id =>27
keyword =>LRG Core Collection
user_id =>0
priority =>30
created =>2014-11-28 06:57:59
modified =>2015-04-05 09:13:21

Comment: than please provide your whole code.. so it can help understand more

Comment: @NishantSolanki What I have provided you is the whole code,only db connections code have been removed

Comment: You could try `trim()`-ing the values of `$key` and `$value`

Comment: Could you please share which part of the error message is unclear and/or unexpected for you? Have you actually verified if there is junk after the document element and have you taken a look how that junk looks like? That normally answers such questions right away. Please update your question.

Comment: @hakre Please view the updated question

Comment: @NishantSolanki I have edited n include my whole code plz have a view

Comment: @Komal Fartiyal: Can't see anything addressing my clarification questions. In that light closed as a duplicated as too localized like the other one. It's not clear why you don't expect the error there. You also didn't share the XML at all you ask about here. Please reduce your example to the bare minimum to show the issue. Also you're doing the mistake to build the XML "by hand" (concatenating strings). This is error prone, a standard suggestion is to use an XML library (that's just FYI not Q&A related).

Comment: Is it clear to you what the term *document element* means? What is your understanding of *junk* that is spoken about in the error message? Can you provide that *junk* with your question? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes,it's clear to me.Could you suggest me XML library link

Comment: @KomalFartiyal I have used your code for generating the xml and its working fine.. unfortunately your question is marked as duplicate, so i will not be able to post the code in answer

Comment: I suggest you first check how that junk looks like. It often shows the cause of the problem, so you have something to take with you.

Comment: @NishantSolanki: The XML creation as outline fails depending on the data used. It can work, but it's not stable. --- There is diverse related Q&A material on site, I suggest a search for on how to create XML based on a database result like (no preference, get more than just one suggestion) [Get MySQL database output via PHP to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5112282/367456).

Comment: @hakre ohh ok.. may be the junk data coming from her database.. it can be the possible issue...

Comment: @KomalFartiyal look at `simpleXML` library.. here is some reference.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php